# Symfony datetime validation

Tags: symfony, datetime, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I am using a jQuery datetime picker plugin which returns the value in the following format

```
2016-10-28 21:00 (Format: YYYY-MM-DD H:i)
```

Here is how I have defined it in entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="preferred_datetime", type="datetime", nullable=false)
 */
private $preferredDateTime;
```

Here is how I am adding the form element

```
$builder->add('preferred_datetime', DateTimeType::class, [
    'label' => 'Preferred Slot *',
    'input' => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'format' => 'y-M-d H:i'
]);
```

This renders the element correctly, however when I submit the form no matter what input value I give it displays the following form error for this field

> This value is not valid

Any pointer on what I am missing here? I want both the date and time in `YYYY-MM-DD H:i` format. my only issue is validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Issue was with the format. It worked when I am using following format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`